# What is a comparable beer to Weihenstephaner Hefeweissbier?

Tags: taste, brewing, recommendations, german-beers, foam

I am trying to think of what US brewed beer tastes most similar to a Weihenstephaner Hefeweissbier...

Answer (score 2):

You can find a discussion about it [here](https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/threads/beers-similar-to-weihenstephaner-hefeweissbier-dunkel.81764/).

A couple of US brewed beers that arise from it are Sierra Nevada Kellerweis and Sly Fox Royal Weiss; but if you'd prefer a more easy-going (and usually cheaper solution), I'd go with [Gösser Dark](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/4477/13892/) - although it's not make in the US (but in Austria) it's widespread across the country.

Answer (score 1):

Erdinger Urweisse and Erdinger Hefeweissbier should also be close. Both are brewed in Erding (roughly 15 miles from Weihenstephan), but reportedly available throughout the world.